# How to make a implement queue for scheduling tasks in WordPress?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-cron, http-api

Is it possible to implement some queuing mechanism for task scheduling? In my plugin, I want to run a task triggered by cron for 5 seconds and if not complete, save the state and call another Async HTTP request so that I don't have a long-running process to eat up user's resources. I want to implement some inbuilt locking mechanism above that so that only single process runs at one time.

Is there any currently active library in WordPress supporting that so that I need not reinvent the wheel? Also, does WordPress provide any way to make Async HTTP request?